# Executing the SQL from shell scripting

Tags: sql, shell

I have a table called `query_master` table which has 4 columns and the 4th column has SQL query as values. In total there are 5 entries in the query table.

Table Structure:

```
S.No --> Key --> Title --> Query
1        100     EG        select * from dual
```

Now my objective is, I have to fetch the SQL queries using shell script from the `query_master` and execute it. The output of that each SQL query should be written on a separate log file, and the log filename should be equal to the name of the title.

Can you please help in achieving this scenario using stored procedures or stored functions which will be more helpful for me.

I need to achieve this using shell scripting.

Comment: What database is this? What specific part of this task do you need help with? Show us what you've done so far and where you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, assuming you're using mysql:

```
awk -F'\t' 'NR!=1 {system("mysql -u user -p -e " $4 " database")}' file
```

Where file is the file containing the table, user is the user and database is the database. Alternatively set these as variables instead of hard coding them like this:

```
awk -F'\t' -v db="database" -v user="user" 'NR!=1 {system(""mysql -u " user " -p -e " $4 " " db)}' file
```

Comment: Hi John, It is oracle database only.. I have created a table like I said earlier which has the query to be executed. Now my objective is, I have to connect to the Db using mysql and execute each queries present in the table. The output of the query should be written in corresponding Title name..???

Comment: I have the script like, for each row, I will connect to database and the output , I ll store in a log file. But if the table entries increases, I have to write again manually one by one entries.. Instead of that is there anyway to execute the complete table queries in one block and the output should ne written accordingly. I m using below query.                  Mysql -s user/pass@dbname<<EOF>>example.log.               select query from query_master where key like '1'; EOF

Answer (score 0):

Make a shell script that accepts a SQL statement from commandline (or inputfile or stdin) and does all things for you like exporting ORACLE_HOME, tnsnames, username, password, redirecting output, calling sqlplus, output formatting, deleting column headers and other sqlplus settings.

With your magicsql.sh (after testing), aim for a solution like

```
magicsql.sh "select key, query from query_master order by key" | while read key query; do
   magicsql.sh "${query}" > /tmp/${key}.out
done
```

Comment: So, u mean to create a function and use it repeatedly. Right?

Comment: A function is also possible. I meant a shellscript that you place somewhere in your PATH. That way the script can be used in a shell-script or for simple commandline queries.